# Angular2 custom forms controls for dynamic forms

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms, dynamicform

Following the docs on [DYNAMIC FORMS](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html), I could run the sample correctly. Now I want to add a custom select: [ng2-select](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-select).

The component is the next one (from the docs):

```
import { Component, Input, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup }        from '@angular/forms';
import { QuestionBase }     from '../question/question-base';
@Component({
  selector: 'df-question',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  templateUrl: 'dynamic-form-question.component.html'
})
export class DynamicFormQuestionComponent {
  @Input() question: QuestionBase<any>;
  @Input() form: FormGroup;
  get isValid() { return this.form.controls[this.question.key].valid; }
}
```

the `html`:

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <label [attr.for]="question.key">{{question.label}}</label>
  <div [ngSwitch]="question.controlType">
    <input *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'" class="form-control" [formControlName]="question.key"
            [id]="question.key" [type]="question.type">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'">
      <ng-select [allowClear]="true"
                [items]="question.options"
                (data)="question.refreshValue($event)"
                (selected)="question.selected($event)"
      </ng-select>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="!isValid">{{question.label}} is required</div>
</div>
```

And the `question-dropdown.ts` is:

```
import { QuestionBase } from './question-base';

export class DropdownQuestion extends QuestionBase<string> {
  controlType = 'dropdown';
  options: {id: string, text: string}[] = [];

  constructor(options: {} = {}) {
    super(options);
    this.options = options['options'] || [];
  }

  public selected(value: any): void {
    console.log('Selected value is: ', value);
  }

  public refreshValue(value: any): void {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

So, it is almost working. The problem is I can not see the `sex` choosen value. The output is the following:

> Saved the following values
>   {"name":"foo","emailAddress":"foo@gmail.com","sex":""}

Yes, I changed a little bit the `question.service.ts`, for those who need it, here it is:

```
import { Injectable }       from '@angular/core';
import { DropdownQuestion } from './question-dropdown';
import { QuestionBase }     from './question-base';
import { TextboxQuestion }  from './question-textbox';
@Injectable()
export class QuestionService {
  // Todo: get from a remote source of question metadata
  // Todo: make asynchronous
  getQuestions() {
    let questions: QuestionBase<any>[] = [
      new DropdownQuestion({
        key: 'sex',
        label: 'Sex',
        options: [
          {id: 'male',  text: 'Male'},
          {id: 'female',  text: 'Female'}
        ],
        order: 3
      }),
      new TextboxQuestion({
        key: 'name',
        label: 'First and Last Name',
        value: '',
        required: true,
        order: 1
      }),
      new TextboxQuestion({
        key: 'emailAddress',
        label: 'Email',
        type: 'email',
        order: 2
      })
    ];
    return questions.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);
  }
}
```

How can I associate the `ng2-select` with the `formgroup` to obtain the right output?

Comment: You haven't bound the formControlName on the select is the first glance seems amiss.

Comment: No it is not, I tried it but it does not allow me

Comment: After digging around in their github a little bit I came across this issue:
https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-select/issues/232
which sounds like it does not support formControlName, formControl, or the ValueAccessors which means you may well be SOL for some time until either they get around to it or you come up with your own select augmentation.